# Working with Executors and Handlers within a Android Service

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

First of all: I am a multi-threading newbie. So forgive my stupidity on this matter :)

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Startup an Android Service and initialize/start several threads next to the main thread (which is the Service thread). Within these threads start new threads which also initialize their own stuff. So you have a few "services"-threads and within these threads some "worker" threads that do dedicated work.
2. When a client binds to the service, it gets the handler of the service through the IBinder object (btw: I am using Messengers for IPC). This is the handler of the service, so its the main-thread handler.
3. Now the bound client sends a message to the service, which is received within the "service handler".
4. The service handler then peeks into the msg.what identifier of the received message and decides to which services-thread this message should be forwarded (it's just a dispatcher).
5. The message is forwarded to the proper destination service-thread which now tries to handle the message in its own message handler. This is the place where the message is actually investigated deeply and based on the message content some other task/worker-thread within this service-thread is put to work, or is updated in its state if it was already working. Some content of the message is handed over to this worker-thread.
6. When the work is done in the worker-thread, a new message is created with the answer given by the worker-thread (the result) and sent to the service-thread which is the "parent" of the worker-thread.
7. The service-thread receives the message from the worker-thread and forwards it to the main-thread of the service which forwards it to the requesting client.
8. The client receives the requested message from the service.

So far so good. What I don't understand are these parts:

- How do I create one or more service-thread(s) using the Concurrency Framework (Executors)? I want the services-thread to be the building blocks of my communication within the service which I can turn on or off depending on what the user wants to do. I have a Blueooth-thread, a Wifi-thread, a NFC-thread as the service-threads.
- How do I create a bunch of threads (or should I say Runnables?) within each services-thread, so I can split the work into several pieces, each with their own functionality or specific task(s)?
- how do I create a message handler within a service-thread, doesn't that mean I have to use a new Messenger too for that thread?
- Do I have to use Messengers also within the worker threads, I think that this is "too much of it". I decompose the message within the specific services-thread, so THAT is the place to translate the incoming message into some "piece of work" that has to be done, right?
- How do I communicate from a worker-thread that the work is done to the services-thread, and from there forwarded to the main-thread?
- I have found a lot of books about multi-threading, but not how to get started being a complete nitwit on this subject. I have looked into the Java Conncurrency in Practice book and read some of the Executors stuff in that book. It explains small parts, but not the complete story from a to z. I need some "let me take you by the hand"-book to introduce me to these concepts without having headaches in 10minutes :)
- How do I communicate between the services-thread mutually so I can have some kind of negotiation process which thread does which communication. E.g. communicate over Bluetooth or WifiDirect? That could mean that one service-thread takes over the communication of the other service-thread.

It's not that I don't understand the small pieces, its more the overview I am missing to get these small pieces put to work together.

The Android part is "finished", so I need only help with the multithreading part within the service...

Comment: general and fairly straightforward tutorial on concurrency: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: @SaadShakil Thanks for sharing. I found this book: [Java7 Concurrency Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/java-7-concurrency-cookbook/book) really helpful in my quest to understand the material too.

Comment: @user504342 as you are newbie , I would suggest Book "Thinking in Java" - only concurrency chapter. Just one chapter will give you in depth knowledge in short time and later you can dig in special topics in book "java concurrency in practice". Both are Excellent resources I followed this approch 3 year back :)

Comment: @Vipin thx for your book suggestion. Although I find the Thinking in Java book a good reference book to look up things in a "How do I do this..."-matter, for tutoring I wouldn't recommend this book.